# ARM system memory map

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, arm, memory-mapping

I am going through ARM infocenter for understanding system memory map of ARM architecture.
In the below link they say ARM memory map is fixed, and External RAM is mapped to
0x60000000 - 0x9FFFFFFF.
http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dai0179b/CHDDBAEC.html

while in this link they say RAM can be re-mapped to any location by AHB decoder.
http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0226a/ch04s03s02.html

Are these memory maps same, Please explain the difference.

Comment: arm makes processor cores, not chips.  the chip vendor determines what the address space is for the processor not arm.  arm does dictate where within the exception table lives (with a strap provided by the chip vendor to pick between two base addresses) and where any on core peripherals are based on a chip vendor provided base address.  the trm for the core defines all of this for you.

Comment: Besides, it doesn't say the ARM memory map is fixed, it says the _Cortex-M3_ memory map is fixed. The ARM7TDMI-based thing in the second link obviously has nothing to do with a Cortex-M3.